# What are the main and sub-types of Ethereum transactions?

Tags: transactions

I'm new to the Ethereum and just want to know about the main and sub-types of Ethereum transactions. Help me please.
Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean with sub types?

Comment: A transaction that fall under the main transaction

Comment: this link might help you out
https://www.doubloin.com/learn/types-of-ethereum-transactions.